# Excel 64bit .xll add-in installation silently fails

Tags: excel, installation, add-in, excel-dna, xll

I have simple add-in written in C# using Excel-DNA:

```
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using System;

namespace ExcelDNA_test {
    public class Functions {
        [ExcelFunction(Name = "CURRENTDATETIME")]
        public static DateTime CurrentDateTime() {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }

        [ExcelFunction(Name = "ADDTWONUMBERS")]
        public static int Add(int a, int b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

After building i get two files for add-in installation:

- ExcelDNA_test-AddIn-packed.xll
- ExcelDNA_test-AddIn64-packed.xll

When i install x64 version on my laptop i can not see new category in add-in options. Also the name of add-in is not loaded properly (shows file name but not add-in name). There are no errors during installation.

I tried to install it on different machines:

- Windows 10 x64, Excel 365 x64 - fail.
- Windows 10 x64, Excel 365 x64 - fail.
- Windows 10 x64, Excel 365 x64 - works.
- Windows 10 x64, Excel 365/2013 x64 - works.
- Windows 10 x64, Excel 2013 x64 - fails (my case).

Maybe there are no libraries installed on my PC for running this add-in?

Additional images:

[image: Add-in name not loaded properly]

Comment: Do you have any antivirus running on the machine? If you're running on a corporate environment, you might have a security app blocking the add-in from being loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Office 2013/2010**

Navigate to *Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall a program -> Right click on Office -> Change.*

When dialog opened select **Add or remove features**. In **Office Shared Features** enable **Visual Basic for Applications**.

[image: Office Shared Features Dialog]

---

**Office 2016/365**

In this releases **Visual Basic for Applications** installed by default. To install your *.xll* follow next steps:

In office navigate to *File -> Options -> Trust center -> Trust center settings*.

When dialog opened navigate to **Macro settings**. Select **Enable all macros**.

[image: Trust Center Settings Dialog]

If you upgraded from Office 2013 with installed **Visual Basic for Applications** component to Office 2016/365 this issue will not appear!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any antivirus running on the machine? If you're running on a corporate environment, you might have a security app blocking the add-in from being loaded.

You might also want to try to add the folder where your `.xll` file is, to the Trusted Locations of Excel:

[image: Excel Trust Center for Excel-DNA add-in]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Windows Defender installed on all machines as antivirus. I don't use corporate environment. I tried specified setting. Add-in successfully installed from all folders on other machine.

Comment: Also i want to add that i have 2 x64 add-ins and both of them don't run on my PC but on other do.